# jquery onclick button change element background next to check/uncheck action

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttonclick

Code below makes that on each click all checkboxes which are not disabled, are checked/unchecked. Also at the first click background of chackboxes parents are chanhging to red.

```
var clicked = false;
    var target = jQuery(".editcheckhour:not(:disabled)");
    jQuery(".checkalledit").click(function() {
    target.prop("checked", !clicked).closest('label').css('background-color','#c00');
    clicked = !clicked;
});
```

On next click I want to change background color back. So the function will not only check/uncheck inputs but also will alternately change checkboxes parents background.

On this JSFIdle demo only first click change backgrounds.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLg7eszb/1/

Is anybody help me do this?

Comment: So use a class instead and toggle the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `toggleClass()`

```js
var clicked = false;
var target = jQuery(".editcheckhour:not(:disabled)");
jQuery(".checkalledit").click(function() {
  target.prop("checked", !clicked).closest('label').toggleClass('bgcolor');
  clicked = !clicked;
});
```

```css
label {
  background-color: #558;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
label > input:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.bgcolor {
  background-color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input class="editcheckhour" type="checkbox">onet</label>
<label>
  <input disabled class="editcheckhour" type="checkbox">two</label>
<label>
  <input class="editcheckhour" type="checkbox">three</label>
<label>
  <input class="editcheckhour" type="checkbox">four</label>

<button type="button" class="checkalledit">on / off</button>
```

Comment: I rarely use toggleClass() so i just forgot about it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Add one class to label default in your code and define that class as default color in your css file.

```
<label><input class="editcheckhour defaultColor"  type="checkbox"> onet</label>
<label><input disabled class="editcheckhour defaultColor"  type="checkbox"> two</label>
<label><input class="editcheckhour defaultColor"  type="checkbox"> three</label>
<label><input class="editcheckhour defaultColor"  type="checkbox"> four</label>
```

the defaultColor class will be in css like

```
defaultColor {
 background-color: #558;
  }
```

another new color will be red like this.

```
newColor {
     background-color: red;
   }
```

on button click simply remove the class and add class to labels on status of the button. To maintain button status write code as:

```
<button type="button" class="checkalledit" data-status="0">on / off</button>
```

after click it will change label background first and then change self status.

```
jQuery(".checkalledit").click(function() {
var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
if(status == 0){
target.prop("checked", !clicked).closest('label').removeClass("defaultColor");
target.prop("checked", !clicked).closest('label').addClass("newColor");
$(this).attr("data-status","1");
  }
  else{
  target.prop("checked", !clicked).closest('label').removeClass("newColor");
   target.prop("checked", !clicked).closest('label').addClass("defaultColor");
$(this).attr("data-status","0");
  }
  });
```